# Selenium C#: How to pull value from input element

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to pull the value of 3745 from the AGX9 Monaural pricing field so I can add it to a DataTable.  However input.Text is coming up empty and I don't see that actual value of 3745 in the HTML for this page.

[image]

Here is the HTML for this input element:

```
<td class="monaural" ng-class="{'has-error' : vm.pricingForm[i].$invalid && vm.pricingForm[i].$dirty}" ng-init="i = ha + 'Monaural'">
    <span class="caption caption-currency">$</span>
    <input class="form-control price-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-touched" type="text" required="" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{3,5}(\.[0-9]{2})?$/" ng-model="vm.data[2][i].value" name="agx9Monaural">
</td>
```

Here is the code I am using to attempt to add the label, monaural, and binaural price to a DataTable.

```
        foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
        {
            var inputFields = row.FindElements(By.TagName("input"));

            //monoaural add to dataTableRow
            dr[1] = inputFields[0].Text;

            //binaural add to dataTableRow
            dr[2] = inputFields[1].Text;

            actualDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the `value` attribute

```
string value = Driver.FindElement(By.Name("agx9Monaural")).GetAttribute("value");
```

Should do it

In your case it would be

```
foreach (IWebElement row in rows)
{
    var inputFields = row.FindElements(By.TagName("input"));

    //monoaural add to dataTableRow
    dr[1] = inputFields[0].GetAttribute("value");

    //binaural add to dataTableRow
    dr[2] = inputFields[1].GetAttribute("value");

    actualDataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!  I made a typo above, the binaural value should be saved into dr[2].

Comment: When **AngularJS** is implemented as part of the application development, then `Text` property does not work, instead we need to get the attribute `value` of that control (HTML having attributes with `ng-XXXX`)